# Can you help me fix this google sheets formula to sort by col5 ascending?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my current formula that works perfectly...

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BNomeoTxYiT4A1A0i8jhRIPtTfZN0GtbQQ4Intp7lMY", "'MASTER'!A2:Z100");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BNomeoTxYiT4A1A0i8jhRIPtTfZN0GtbQQ4Intp7lMY", "'SPOTS'!A2:Z100")},"select * where LOWER(Col1) contains '"&lower(Structure!N$8)&"' and Col2 = date '"&TEXT(Structure!M$8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

All I want to do is sort by Col5 ascending.  I've tried to add it in multiple ways and keep getting an error.  Can anyone help edit this formula to add "sort by col5 asc"?

Comment: Where do you have `Order By Col5`? It should be at the end of the query. Note its **not** 'sort by'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1BNomeoTxYiT4A1A0i8jhRIPtTfZN0GtbQQ4Intp7lMY", "'MASTER'!A2:Z100");
 IMPORTRANGE("1BNomeoTxYiT4A1A0i8jhRIPtTfZN0GtbQQ4Intp7lMY", "'SPOTS'!A2:Z100")},
 "where LOWER(Col1) contains '"&LOWER(Structure!N$8)&"' 
    and Col2 = date '"&TEXT(Structure!M$8, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  order by Col5 asc", 1)
```